# Spelling mistake in newly created tag

Tags: support, tags

Today I came across a newly created tag, [jenkisn](/questions/tagged/jenkisn) on SO. It seems like there is a spelling mistake in the tag. The tag should be `jenkins`. I searched on google also for the word jenkisn but there was no such technology.

If I am wrong somewhere then please forgive me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That tag has 0 uses, so it will disappear shortly.  The person who created it probably noticed the typo and corrected it on their question.

Comment: Indeed, he got just enough reputation to create a tag. [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11132848/revisions) - it was fixed later by someone else with sharp eyes. :)